# I want to extract by using regexp extract for the below data pattern

Tags: sql, regex, google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery

I have data pattern

```
"<AccessEntry: role=READER,
userbyemail=sjack@gmail.com>"

"<AccessEntry: role=WRITER, 
specialgroup=projectReaders>"
```

The data is in Bigquery table. I want to extract userbyemail/specialgroup in other column and `sjack@gmail.com/projectReaders` in other column. The values are dynamic but I gave you the pattern to understand.

I tried regexp but I just got the value of role In different column but unable to get other values in some other column.

Comment: The data is in different rows.

Comment: Could you share what have you tried so far ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/string_functions#regexp_extract_all) to Returns an array of all substrings of data that match the regular expression, and [`ARRAY_TO_STRING`](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/array_functions#array_to_string) to convert the returned array into a string :

```
with cte as (
    select '<AccessEntry: role=READER, userbyemail=sjack@gmail.com>" "<AccessEntry: role=WRITER, specialgroup=projectReaders>' as col
)
select *, ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(col, r', (.+?)='), '/') as col1,
          ARRAY_TO_STRING(REGEXP_EXTRACT_ALL(col, r'=([^,;]+?)>'), '/') as col2
from cte;
```